# how to play a audio from a audio stream url using python (don't want to use vlc)

Tags: python, http, audio, server, python-requests

I have a audio url, It can be simply played from a browser and python-vlc library but I want another way to play the audio using requests and libs like pydub, playsound etc,..

I don't use python-vlc because I think that it requires vlc player to be installed in our computer

and please help me in downloading the audio inn mp3

Comment: Have you tried something? is there any code you're having issues with? SO is not a place to ask for someone to write the code for you or asking for recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember, to play an audio file from a URL using Python without relying on the VLC library, one can use a combination of the `requests` library to download the file and libraries like `pydub` and `playsound` to play it.

Something like this:

```py
import requests
from pydub import AudioSegment
from playsound import playsound
import io

audio_url = 'YOUR_AUDIO_URL_HERE'

response = requests.get(audio_url)
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Use BytesIO for in-memory byte stream
    audio_stream = io.BytesIO(response.content)

    # Load the audio file using pydub
    audio = AudioSegment.from_file(audio_stream, format="mp3")

    # Save the audio to a file
    file_path = 'downloaded_audio.mp3'
    audio.export(file_path, format="mp3")

    # Play the audio file
    playsound(file_path)
else:
    print("Failed to download the audio file")
```